# How to select in jquery relatively to current position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For example `$(". > a")` or may be `$("this > a" )` or may be `$(this)("a")`

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail. Relevant to the current position of what? the cursor? the field with focus? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish from what you have posted so far.

Comment: @Jeremy Current element and CSS selector :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("a", this)` , it'll search for `<a>` within the context of the second argument `this`.

You can provide a a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery as the second argument to use as context to search within.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: That's not the same; it will find decedents too.

Comment: @SLaks, I didn't realize that was the question was specific to finding children of the current element. I thought that the question was more general as to how to select within the current element. Your answer is, of course, the best way to find direct children of the current element.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to write

```
$(this).children('a')
```

Note that `this` isn't the "current position"; it's the context in which a function was invoked.
In an `each` callback or event handler, it happens to be the element that the callback was invoked for.

For other selectors, you can call jQuery's [other traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), such as `.parent()` or `.find()`.

Comment: That makes pretty good sense, I wouldn't have interpreted that from his question, nice catch.

Comment: The `.find()` function is also of interest.